# C# : get the file path of picturebox onclick

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, picturebox

I have created a function that loops a folder and retrieves each image file and draw a picturebox on the form.
Here is the function :

```
    private void Create_Controls(string Img_path)
    {
        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
        p.Size = new Size(138, 100);
        p.Location = new Point(6, 6);
        p.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Img_path);
        p.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

So what i need to do is : whenever i click on any picturebox on the form , a message popup with the image file path.

So i thought about adding a custom event :

```
p.Click += delegate { Pop_Up(); };
```

AND

```
    private void Pop_Up()
    {
        /* POP UP MESSAGE WITH Picturebox image file path*/
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
p.Click += new EventHandler(Pop_Up);

...

private void Pop_Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var pb = sender as PictureBox;
  if(pb != null)
    MessageBox.Show(pb.ImageLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the property [ImageLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation) of the PictureBox . The property gets or sets the path or URL for the image to display in the PictureBox.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Tag` property for this.

something like this .

```
private void Create_Controls(string Img_path)
{
  PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
  p.Size = new Size(138, 100);
  p.Location = new Point(6, 6);
  p.Tag  = Img_path;
  p.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Img_path);
  p.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

  this.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

---

```
private void Pop_Up()
{
   MessageBox.Show(p.Tag);
}
```

For more on this [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag).

Answer (score 1):

Then along with what HatSoft says, change your `Pop_up()` method like:

```
  private void Pop_Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(((PictureBox)sender).ImageLocation);
   }
```

But maybe a bit more elegant and checking if it is indeed a `PictureBox` etc.